# Difference between Elmah and Elmah.Contrib.WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, elmah, error-logging

I am confused between Elmah and Elmah.Contrib.WebApi. And which one is best option for Web API. Iam already using Nlog for exception logging along with Tracing in Web API. So How Elmah is different from all of them. What is the exact need to going for Elmah??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is useful for catching errors that you did not catch and log yourself. I am using it for a MVC application and it sends me an email when I have an issue that I need to resolve.  I can be proactive and I am working on errors before I can hear from the user.

Answer (score 0):

[Elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) addresses your default application error logging. However when you're using Web API, for example ASP.NET MVC Web API, you need some extra logic to log your Web API errors within your Elmah data store.

There are a few ways to address this requirement, one being to use the [Elmah.Contrib.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi) package.

Once the package is imported to your project remember to follow any implementation requires, i.e. startup filter registry (as noted here)